# ifconfig-changes not saved after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ifconfig

I changed my network device names, but they aren't saved after rebooting. I also deactivated interface wlan0, but it is still on again after rebooting.
Using UBUNTU.

Here `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


# The wan0 network interface
auto wan0
iface wan0 inet dhcp

# The eth0 network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I am sorry, is it wan0 or wlan0? You seem to be mentioning both and I sense this may be just a matter of a typo somewhere.

Comment: @BorisEpstein `wan0` and `wlan0`. `wlan0` is the interface that should stay disabled and `wan0` and `eth0` are the interfaces that get back to their original name after boot.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else is here looking for help in later versions of ubuntu server (17.x). They have switched from `network` (`/etc/network/interfaces`) to `netplan` (`/etc/netplan/*.yml`).

Hopefully this helps someone else/saves them some time.

Simple sample for a static IP configuration.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.100/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `ifconfig` to configure your network interfaces, the changes will be lost after reboot.

To make your changes persistent, you need to modify configuration files like `/etc/network/interfaces`. For example, to disable an interface you can simply remove its config part from the file.

You can check `man interfaces` for available options and format of network config file for Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem is that `wlan0` doesn't has an entry in the file, but is again available after reboot.

Answer (score 2):

For the interface name part, you should check this file (if it's there on Ubuntu, I have it on Debian):

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Edit it if needed as per the comment inside

If there's no such file (in recent udev), there's still a specific package you can use to have the renaming done at boot: `ifrename`, or you can add some boot script yourself.

for deactivating wlan0, there are different things beside the /etc/network/interfaces. There's always NetworkManager lurking around. It's handy but it often interferes with the settings. See if you can do something with NetworkManager graphically or using `nmcli` , like:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

There's also the `rfkill` command (rfkill package). It uses the same backend as `nmcli radio`. For example you can prevent all wireless related activity with `rfkill block all`

Comment: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` doesn't exist ... so is there are way to rename the connections using `nmcli`?

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu v17 when the static ip parameters in the file "interfaces"  were set after rebooting the machine it gets the IP address from DHCP. (After this `/etc/init.d/networking restart` or ifdown/ifup work well but they are only temporary solutions). It is enough to replace the "dhcp4: yes" row to "dhcp4: no" in the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file and after reboot the settings in the file "interfaces" are asserted without giving any further settings in the netplan file. (A note: in man pages the syntax talks about only "dhcp4: true" with static IP settings(!))